# Is there a way to delete all iPhone application data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Update:

The app is running on the device of an ad-hoc user.

I just want to delete a single application's data.

---

Original question:

Is there a way to completely wipe the an iPhone application's directory easily?

I want to delete preferences, documents, caches, everything.

I'd like to do this programmatically within the app so I could distribute it to an Ad-Hoc user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them delete the app from their phone first.  That will delete the application folder.  Then they can install a fresh copy with no saved files in the app's directory.

Comment: I didn't think app data was deleted when this happened. Do you have a document that verifies this?

Comment: I've been doing this for a while - since each app is sandboxed, all the data is stored within the app's directory. I know that this will reset settings, NSUserDefaults, etc.. as well.

Comment: It won't delete items in the keychain though, so if you have login credentials saved they will persist after reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the app running in the simulator and you want to send it to an ad-hoc user? Technically, ad-hoc copies of the app need to be compiled for the ARM architecture and codesigned with an ad-hoc distribution certificate - so a copy from the simulator won't do any good.

If you just want the other person to run the app in their copy of the simulator, you can go to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ and start deleting stuff, though.

Comment: This is for an ad-hoc distibuted app on a beta tester's device.